# Creating multiple quantile outputs based on condition of a value of a specific row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have a df that has columns such as below:

```
   xx_id          interval_start_time                   interval_end_time      percentage_rate  
    bd63             2019-04-01 20:00:00.000                  2019-04-01 20:30:00.000       0.208   
    a519             2019-04-01 22:00:00.000                  2019-04-01 22:30:00.000       0.083
```

I wanted to calc the percentiles for the ***percentage_rate column***  ( multiple percentiles like p5 p25 p50 p75 p90 ) based on the ***interval_start_time column***. Something maybe where i can input the day and time for the ***interval_start_time column*** ( so I can do it for the different values in that column since that column contains different days and time intervals) and it would give me the percentiles or quantiles that I wanted?

Thanks for the time

Comment: Not 100% sure what you need, perhaps you could clarify the question. But as far as best methods to start looking at, one might be https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html   You can use custom buckets in this method. to find the ranges of your quantiles

Comment: The output would just be the different quantiles as stated above for the percentage_rate column. But based on the interval_start_time column value since there are different values for that column that I wanted to calc the quantiles for, sorry if that was unclear @run-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df['interval_start_time'].dt.day)['percentage_rate'].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, [25,50,75,100]))
```

You can change "day" to whatever your want your dates to group by. Make sure `df['interval_start_time']` is a datetime column. You can also change the values in `[]` to display whatever percentiles that your interested in.

Comment: Thanks so essentially, I would have to run this code, 5 times if I wanted it for 5 different interval_start_time values?

Comment: yes, so if you wanted to group your dates by month, you would change day to month.

Comment: what if I wanted to change it by day and time? Like the only differences in the values id be calculating for would be something like 2019-04-01 20:30:00.000 and 2019-04-02 20:00:00.000. The only changes would be the day and the time not the month or year , Thanks!

Comment: I was more concerned only with the day and the actual time like 20:00:00.000 and 20:30:00.000 or 10:00:00.000, thanks! @Ben Pap

Comment: If you want to calculate for all the times exactly 2019-04-01 20:30:00.000, you would just leave off .dt.day

Comment: Thnx! so would it look like df.groupby(df['interval_start_time'][2019-04-01 20:30:00.000]) ? @Ben Pap

Comment: ```df.groupby(df['interval_start_time'])['percentage_rate'].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, [25,50,75,100]))``` You will get back a column with all the times, and another one with all the percentile values for those times.

Comment: So this would give me all the percentiles for every time slot that is in the df? if I only wanted specific time slots would there be a way for that? sorry for the questions :/ @Ben Pap

Comment: you would need to filter your times before doing the group by. ie ```df2=df[df'['interval_start_time'] == '2019-04-01 20:30:00.000'].copy()```(or you could do < a time, > a time ect...) then run the code on df2.

Comment: Thanks ! last question if thats ok - for some of the outputs - it has too many decimals and doesnt display all the quantile calculation as a result:

2019-04-01 15:30:00    [0.29725, 0.7424999999999999, 0.96400000000000...

Is there any way I can round them to 2 decimals with the calculation? @Ben Pap

Comment: Change it to this: ```np.percentile(x, [25,50,75,100]).round(2)```. That should work.